# Devise destroy registration action to also destroy all authentications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm using DEvise for registration and omniauth for authentication through twitter/facebook, I want to destroy all authentications when a users destroys his account registration with Devise. What do I need to add to my registrations destroy method for this?

```
RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def destroy
  resource.destroy 
  set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed
  sign_out_and_redirect(self.resource)
end


AuthenticationsController

def destroy
  @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
  @authentication.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed authentication."
  redirect_to authentications_url
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you followed rbates on this one. The way he set it up was users having many authentications so correct me if I'm wrong.

You just need this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authentications, :dependent => :destroy
end
```